# Can execute Code Dynamically in monotouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

In C# .net we can run code dynamically by using `System.Codedom.Provider`. Like the same is there any possibility to execute the code dynamically in Monotouch (iPhone/iPad).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you need to execute dynamic code?

Comment: thank you for quick reply. Requirement for my iPad Monotouch application to execute code (string) at runtime in monotouch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible. First because the limitation in how Xamarin.iOS [actually works](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations) (it doesn't run like a regular .NET apps, but instead compiled to a plain iOS app)  and because the [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime) model in Apple Appstore. After all, you can't declare an app to be safe or regulation conforming if the behavior could change anytime.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information Can you please tell me that in Monodroid c# to go app is executing c# coding dynamically how they did? Please verify this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gregshackles.csharptogo&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd

Comment: Monodroid and Monotouch works very differently. As you can see in Monodroid, there's an actual Mono running http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/architecture while in Monotouch, it's just compiled to plain iOS without any JIT features http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_1_-_understanding_the_xamarin_mobile_platform#1.1.compilation . The dynamic coding in Mono (and .NET) require JIT.

Comment: On the other hand, JIT from a javascript is allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054732/is-it-prohibited-using-of-jitjust-in-time-compiled-code-in-ios-app-for-appstor 
Why didn't Monotouch use it? It could be much slower than native code, or perhaps it just doesn't support the Mono paradigm.

Comment: Thank you So much Martheen I wasted 2-3 days for R&D you saved my rest of the days... :)

Answer (score 6):

Since Xamarin.iOS version 7.2 there is some basic support for C#'s dynamic feature. From the [release notes](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_7/xamarin.ios_7.2/):

> Experimental:
>   C# dynamic support. We made it possible to use C# dynamic with Xamarin.iOS but the feature is very complex and we need early adopters let us know what dynamic code they run on other platforms or would like to run on Xamarin.iOS.

I've successfully compiled and executed dynamic access of anonymous types:

```
 dynamic d = new { name = "x" };
 tmp = d.name;
```

Currently you need to add a Microsoft.CSharp.dll as a dependency -- otherwise you'll get an exception similar to this:

```
Error CS0518: The predefined type `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported (CS0518) (DynamicSupportOniOS)
Error CS1969: Dynamic operation cannot be compiled without `Microsoft.CSharp.dll' assembly reference (CS1969) (DynamicSupportOniOS)
```

Unfortunately neither ExpandoObject nor Json.Net's JObject work right now:

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.NewProp = "demo"; // this still works
Console.WriteLine(x.NewProp); // fails with Xamarin.iOS 7.2

dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");
Console.WriteLine(d.number); // fails with Xamarin.iOS 7.2
```

I've created two bug reports for this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20081 and https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20082.