# Xamarin.Forms deserialising json to an object

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, json-deserialization

```
var myObjectList = (List<MyObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponseMessage, typeof(List<MyObject>));
```

the above works to deserialise a JSON string to a list of custom objects when the JSON  has the following format

```
[
   {
     "Name": "Value"
   },
   {
     "Name": "Value"
   },
   {
     "Name": "Value"
   },
   "Name": "Value"
   }
]
```

I don't know how to do the same when the format is like this

```
{
    "ReturnedData" : [
       {
         "Name": "Value"
       },
       {
         "Name": "Value"
       },
       {
         "Name": "Value"
       },
       "Name": "Value"
       }
    ]

}
```

I can get the data like this

```
JObject information = JObject.Parse(strResponseMessage);
foreach (dynamic data in information)
{
   //convert to object here
}
```

and that works for Android but it seems that you cannot use a type of 'dynamic' for iOS as I get the error:

```
Object type Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeMemberBinder cannot be converted to target type: System.Object[]
```

What step am I missing to convert the second JSON string to the first?

Comment: It's an object with one field `ReturnedData` that is a collection of objects that have one field `Name`.

Comment: Why not use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(result);` instead of `(List<MyObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponseMessage, typeof(List<MyObject>))` ?

Comment: I used it because that was what my search turned up, but will give it a go. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies - I was able to solve it as follows

```
JObject information = JObject.Parse(strResponseMessage);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strResponseMessage["ReturnedData "]);

var myObjectList = (List<MyObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json , typeof(List<MyObject>));
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: It's not working for me. I faced the same problem again.

Answer (score 2):

If JsonConvert is JSON.Net just instead of List use

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<MyObject> ReturnedData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the **dynamic** keyword on **iOS** as its forbidden to generate code as it states in this [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/).

Quote:-

> No Dynamic Code Generation
>
> Since the iPhone's kernel prevents an application from generating code dynamically Mono on the iPhone does not support any form of dynamic code generation.
>
> These include:
>
> The System.Reflection.Emit is not available.

Quote:-

> System.Reflection.Emit
>
> The lack of System.Reflection. Emit means that no code that depends on runtime code generation will work. This includes things like:
>
> The Dynamic Language Runtime.
>
> Any languages built on top of the Dynamic Language Runtime.

Apparently there is some support creeping in from v7.2 as can be seen in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704385/can-execute-code-dynamically-in-monotouch) - See @Rodja answer.  - **however** - its very experimental and has **flaws** preventing this from fully working.

Your best approach would be to process the **JObject** - **without** - reying on the **dynamic** keyword and you will be alright on both **Android** and **iOS**.