# Unable to parse a simple string on JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, xamarin.forms

I'm unable to parse this string in Xamarin via JSON.NET

```
{   "errors": [
    {
      "code": "SECURITY_TOKEN_EXPIRED",
      "message": "security token expired",
      "sourceErrorCode": "SECURITY_TOKEN_EXPIRED",
      "sourceMessage": "error validating JWT Error"
    }   ] 
}
```

into the Model

```
public class Error
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sourceErrorCode")]
    public string SourceErrorCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sourceMessage")]
    public string SourceMessage { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public IList<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

I call

> ErrorType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);

I use the same method for pretty much every other json payload that the server is sending me, but the thread goes into an infinite loop upon hitting this line. Any idea why it is misbehaving here?

Comment: Try renaming your `ErrorRoot.Errors` property. It might go into some loop because of the same names. Another thing you could try to detect the error is copy the JSON and then go into Visual Studio, click _Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes_. Then it will give you the classes etc. maybe you see some error there with your code

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm using as you NewtonSoft.json for that and I don't have any problem. Maybe It's simple if you rename your fields as your json.

Comment: How we can expect to deserialize into ErrorRoot if we execute following line: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString); . It will deserialize into Sytem.Object, correct?

Comment: Try update your model. Delete JsonProperties and change names to code,message,sourceErrorCode... etc.

Comment: @kat1330 `It will deserialize into Sytem.Object, correct? ` No. it is `JObject` in fact, which can be used as `ErrorType["errors"][0]["code"]`

Comment: @L.B Thanks. Are we talking about following method: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm It refer to System.Object. Or I am wrong again?

Comment: @kat1330 Yes, and try to cast it to JObject for this json in question :) (BTW: to give you more info. It can be JArray depending on the json :) ) People learns new things everyday, doesn't it?

Comment: @L.B I am not following you. He Said that trying to deserialize into ErrorRoot. Before he edited post he used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString); So , I asked how is it possible to deserialize into ErrorRoot because it will return System.Object? This is what I was confused.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on "regular" .Net.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/8r0m2C.

Comment: @kat1330 the problem is not in deserialization. OP's code is working... Question isn't clear why he gets an `infinite loop`. I voted it to close `Unclear what is asked`. But it could be also `Not reproducable`

Comment: @L.B Original question is: "Unable to parse a simple string on JSON.NET". And he clearly said that he was not able to deserialize into ErrorRoot. Why it goes to infinite loop is second question maybe. And who knows that??? There are no any other info related to infinite loop. How I can know what impact to his code? Code is clear and simple, it should process normally.

Comment: What version of Json.NET are you using on xamarin.forms?  It isn't "officially" supported there.  Whichever version you use apparently needs to disable use of `dynamic` and code generation, see [Xamarin.Forms deserialising json to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573168).  While the current version of the question deserializes to an explicit type, the original version did not.

Comment: Why does "crashmstr" edited the question and changed the code that the OP originally placed ? The original said `ErrorType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);` !

Comment: @Jim OK. I reverted it back...

Comment: @L.B yes, great thing, I was wondering ? :-) Thanks

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. I can deserialize to JObject as well as             var ErrorType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< ErrorRoot>(responseString);
on XForms 2.3.2.127 and 2.3.3.168. Installed Json v9.0.1

Comment: thanks all, I'l look into it. I'd put the problem aside to focus on other work. will look into it agin