# dynamic in android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i have seen in the link  below:
[Can execute Code Dynamically in monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704385/can-execute-code-dynamically-in-monotouch)

that it is impossible to use dynamic in ios xamarin. how about in Andoid xamarin?

I tried to do the following:

```
            dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            MyDynamic.A = "A";
            MyDynamic.B = "B";
```

However, when I want to access MyDinamic.A, it says that Unknown Member: A.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Edit:I also have added the Microsoft.Csharp dll in the solution reference as per the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I used dynamic in android context to execute bitwise operations on generic variables - it seems to work normally. Maybe it's the ExpandoObject which is not fully supported? I assume the error happens in runtime?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure which IDE did you use for developing your xamarin android app, by my side I used VS2015, and the error is

> Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

This is because when use the dynamic keyword in your project. The assembly contains the C# runtime binder. To solve this issue, we need to add reference to Microsoft.CSharp library(Microsoft.CSharp.dll) in our project:

[image]

After adding this reference, your code runs well by my side.

But I'm not sure if the Xamarin.Android will limit the use of dynamic object, through I didn't find any limitation in xamarin's official document. For more information about dynamic object, you can refer to:

[System.Dynamic.DynamicObject Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Dynamic.DynamicObject/)

[System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject/)

Answer (score 5):

Go to `NuGet Package Manager` > `Manage NuGet packages` menu. Then change `Source` to `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`. After adding, it should compile successfully.

[image: 1]